# How can I get the number of lines of Text component in React Native?

Tags: react-native

How can I get the number of lines of Text component in React Native?

I want to show "Read more button" if the number of lines of text component is over 4.

Is there any props to get the number of lines?

I already know there is a numberOfLines props in Text Component but it's just about setting the number of lines. Am I right?

Comment: you can also hit a right mark if my answer helps you and if it is a right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In current version this feature is not available in RN, But there is the best library you can use
[react-native-read-more-text](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-read-more-text) which will give results as you want.

Answer (score 0):

from onContentSizeChange props of textinput you will get height and then divide the height to get number of lines

```
onContentSizeChange={e =>
          console.log(e.nativeEvent.contentSize.height)
        }
```

for more check [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#oncontentsizechange)

Comment: He is asking for Text, not for TextInput.